# Jquery attr change structure html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i have jquery in there i want to make my structure of my html change when i click my `checkbox` 
for example :
when i checked my `checkbox` my `.col-md-4 col-md-push-2` will change to `.col-md-6`
and when i uncheck it will back to normal

here my jquery :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        $(".col-md-4").attr("class", "col-md-6");
        $(".col-md-push-2").attr("class", "");
    });
});
</script>
```

and here my view :

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-2 space business-fields yes box">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-2 space business-fields yes box">
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="try">
```

in there i can make it change if i check it, but i can't make how to change back again when i uncheck it.

have someone tell me what improvements do i have to make to the code to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You could toggle these classes, e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $colmd2 = $(".col-md-push-2");
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        $(".col-md-4, .col-md-6").toggleClass("col-md-4 col-md-6");
        $colmd2.toggleClass("col-md-push-2");
    });
});
```

Comment: a oke, but can make it without `fake` text.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option. Use This:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
           $(".space").addClass("col-md-6").removeClass("col-md-4 col-md-push-2");
        }else{
            $(".space").removeClass("col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4 col-md-push-2");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: its add `col-md-6` and not removing `col-md-4 col-md-push-2` in my structure

Answer (score 0):

> i think this is what exactly you are looking for...when checks add col-md-6  when uncheck get back its col-md-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

                if($(this).prop("checked") == true){

                    $(".col-md-push-2").addClass("col-md-6");
 $(".col-md-push-2").removeClass("col-md-4");

                }

                else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){

                    $(".col-md-push-2").addClass("col-md-4");
 $(".col-md-push-2").removeClass("col-md-6");

                }

            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-2 space business-fields yes box">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-2 space business-fields yes box">
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="try">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code ..

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
       if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {
           $('.col-md-4').addClass('col-md-6').removeClass('col-md-4 col-md-push-2')
       }
       else {
           $('.col-md-6').addClass('col-md-4 col-md-push-2').removeClass('col-md-6')
       }
   });
```